# Error in sage tutorial coding theory

Tags: sage

I have just installed sage 6.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 and I have tried the tutorial in coding theory as follow:

```
MS = MatrixSpace(GF(2),4,7)

G = MS([[1,1,1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,1,1,0,0], [0,1,0,1,0,1,0], [1,1,0,1,0,0,1]])

C = LinearCode(G)
```

In the third evaluation, sage produced error as follow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "_sage_input_4.py", line 10, in <module>
    exec compile(u'open("___code___.py","w").write("# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-\\n" + _support_.preparse_worksheet_cell(base64.b64decode("QyA9IExpbmVhckNvZGUoRyk="),globals())+"\\n"); execfile(os.path.abspath("___code___.py"))
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/tmp/tmpXyxNvC/___code___.py", line 2, in <module>
    exec compile(u'C = LinearCode(G)
  File "", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/coding/linear_code.py", line 785, in __init__
    facade_for = gen_mat.row(0).parent()
  File "matrix_mod2_dense.pyx", line 576, in sage.matrix.matrix_mod2_dense.Matrix_mod2_dense.row (build/cythonized/sage/matrix/matrix_mod2_dense.c:5387)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 432, in VectorSpace
    return FreeModule(K, rank=dimension, sparse=sparse, inner_product_matrix=inner_product_matrix)
  File "factory.pyx", line 366, in sage.structure.factory.UniqueFactory.__call__ (build/cythonized/sage/structure/factory.c:1327)
  File "factory.pyx", line 410, in sage.structure.factory.UniqueFactory.get_object (build/cythonized/sage/structure/factory.c:1679)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 380, in create_object
    return FreeModule_ambient_field(base_ring, rank, sparse=sparse)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 4972, in __init__
    FreeModule_ambient_pid.__init__(self, base_field, dimension, sparse=sparse)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 4893, in __init__
    FreeModule_ambient_domain.__init__(self, base_ring=base_ring, rank=rank, sparse=sparse)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 4709, in __init__
    FreeModule_ambient.__init__(self, base_ring, rank, sparse)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 4184, in __init__
    FreeModule_generic.__init__(self, base_ring, rank=rank, degree=rank, sparse=sparse)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 714, in __init__
    self.element_class()
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 896, in element_class
    C = element_class(self.base_ring(), self.is_sparse())
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sage/modules/free_module.py", line 6721, in element_class
    import sage.modules.vector_real_double_dense
  File "vector_real_double_dense.pyx", line 1, in init sage.modules.vector_real_double_dense (build/cythonized/sage/modules/vector_real_double_dense.c:5611)
  File "__init__.pxd", line 155, in init sage.modules.vector_double_dense (build/cythonized/sage/modules/vector_double_dense.c:11813)
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .polynomial import *
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/polynomial.py", line 19, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq, inv
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    from .linalg import *
  File "/usr/local/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 29, in <module>
    from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite, _umath_linalg
ImportError: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem? I am new to sage!

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`

Comment: It works fine now! Great (y) @max taldykin

Comment: Anyway, I have tried some other example in the tutorial and so far so good. Until the one example, `C = codes.HammingCode(5,GF(2))` and `C.covering_radius() # optional - gap_packages (Guava package)` it produced error again. This means that I need to install **gap_package** right?

Comment: Not sure, but try `sudo apt-get install gap-guava`.

Comment: Sage won't know about the gap-guava, you will need to install `gap_packages` via Sage's `sage -i gap_packages`.

Comment: @kcrisman I have done now. It works but it takes time to `make`. I wonder why sage does not include this package!

Comment: Because it is really huge and takes time to `make`, as you say.  Most users of Sage will not need it, and those who will should be motivated enough to do this command, as opposed to some other things which are standard... it's not an exact science, of course, deciding what should be optional and what standard!  You could always propose on sage-devel@googlegroups.com that it be standard, though I suspect you'd get some pushback.